# How to specifiy both a method argument and part of a data frame in corr

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-mining

In the below code, I wish to specifiy 'pearson' as method but this does not seem possible if I am at the same time defining an argument with a dataframe's column. Therefore, I am not able to simply do corr(method='pearson'), any solution or way around this?

```
df_dataframe1['Food'].corr(df_dataframe1['Ingredient'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DataFrame.corrwith` with `method='pearson'`:

```py
df_dataframe[['Food']].corrwith(df_dataframe1[['Ingredient']], method='pearson')
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'corrwith'

Comment: Try without the `['Food']`

Comment: If that doesn’t work, try `corr`, not `corrwith`